# pipe not working as expected when combined with sleep()

Tags: c, pipe

I have a code snippet like this (test code, so don't mind the style too much):

```
int main() {
    int fd[2];
    pipe(fd);
    int id = fork();

    if (id > 0) {
        char *line = "apple";
        close(fd[0]);
        for (;;) {
            int written;
            if (written = write(fd[1], line, 7) == -1) {
                break;
            }
            printf("written %d\n", written);
            sleep(1);
        }
        close(fd[1]);
    }
    else {
        char line[10];
        close(fd[1]);
        int raed;
        while (raed = read(fd[0], line, 10) > 0) {
            printf(line);
        }
        printf("read %d\n", raed);
        close(fd[0]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It keeps printing "written 0". However, if I comment out `sleep(1)`, it still always prints "written 0" but there will be "apple" printed. I don't know what is going on. Why can't I keep the `sleep(1)` and let it print every 1 second? And why does it write 0 rather than 6?

Comment: `write` does not stop at a zero byte, and this code could invalidly try to access `"apple"[6]`.  (That's not the cause of the issues.)

Comment: @aschepler oh that's part of my test though, I wanted to see what would happen if I specify a longer size than the actual string :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if (written = write(fd[1], line, 7) == -1)`

there is a mistake use `if ((written = write(fd[1], line, 7)) == -1)`

most of the time coders forget this often...

Comment: That does solve the "written 0" problem but it's still not printing "apple"

Comment: If I move it outside the while loop, it would only print if raed <= 0 right? That's not the right logic here

Comment: (raed = read(fd[0], line, 10) > 0) instead use ((raed = read(fd[0], line, 10)) > 0)

Comment: you have to have parentheses as == has higher precedence than assignment operator...

Comment: It's printing "written 7" every second but not "apple". Seems the child is not reading anything.

Comment: Change `printf(line);` to `printf("%s", line); flush(stdout);`

Comment: @EdHeal `fflush(stdout)` works! But why do I need to flush it manually?

Comment: @Xufeng - The buffer gets flushed when the buffer is full or a new line is in the buffer. This is the usual behaviour of `printf`

Comment: use printf("%s\n", line); instead of printf( line);

Comment: @xufeng - Not in your code. Could use `char *line="apple\n";` then it will. Should also use `write(fd[1], line, strlen(line))`

Comment: @Xufeng "apple" will have a NULL character at the end to march the finishing of the string, and no newline character...

Comment: @EdHeal Oh yes, sorry I mixed up new line and null terminator :)

Comment: @TrilokM Yes I mixed up :)